# How to detect duplicated rows in SQL with where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with this sample data:

```
place_id    email
----------------------------
   3        uno@uno.com
   3        dos@dos.com
   4        tres@tres.com
   5        uno@uno.com
   6        uno@uno.com
   3        dos@dos.com
   4        tres@tres.com
```

I want to show the emails that are in different places, I tried this query:

```
select email, count(email)
from table
group by email
having count(email) > 1
```

The problem is, this shows the duplicated rows in the same place, and I need to show only rows in different places. For example show only the email "uno@uno.com", that is in the places 3, 5 y 6, and no the "dos@dos.com" that is repeated in the same place.

Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: what is your rdbms? mysql, oracle, sqlserver,psotgre?

Comment: What if you have an additional row: `3        tres@tres.com` would you then want it to be shown in the final output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the emails, you can use aggregation:

```
select email
from t
group by email
having min(place) <> max(place);
```

If you want the places as well in a unique list, you can do:

```
select distinct place, email
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.email = t.email and t2.place <> t.place
             );
```

And, although you can use window functions, the solution is not as obvious:

```
select distinct place, email
from (select t.*,
             min(t.place) over (partition by t.email) as min_place,
             max(t.place) over (partition by t.email) as max_place
      from t
     ) t
where min_place <> max_place;
```

Comment: I used the first query and it's ok, but with a little problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use windowed `COUNT(*)` supported on modern RDBMS.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT t.*, COUNT(DISTINCT place_id) OVER(PARTITION BY email) AS cnt
      FROM tab t) sub
WHERE cnt > 1
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6b86bdf0c2d15c9f6b6003ded89a42db)**

---

SQL Sever/MariaDB/MySQL 8.0/PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY email) AS cnt
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT place_id, email FROM tab) s
      )sub
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

**[DB-Fiddle.com Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pEQyFgqLh7xedBd1YFQ9LN/1)**

Comment: No, you can't use `distinct` in other DBMS such `SQL Server`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Here you go

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `GROUP BY` clause with `HAVING` clause to filter out the unique place

```
select place_id, email
from table t
group by place_id, email 
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, i tried the first solution of Gordon Linoff and it's worked. But i have a little problem, i have a "where" clause, and this:

```
select email, count(email) from data where place = 2 or place=3 or place=4 group by email having min(place) <> max(place)
```

show the same results as:

```
select email, count(email) from data where place = 2 or place=3 group by email having min(place) <> max(place)
```

because it's an or condition, but i don't know how to repair and in the first query how to show only the items that are in all these places, not only in two of them.